# Import error: No module named rospkg/yaml

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to this error(import error: No module named rospkg)( Still not yet fixed)

> http://answers.ros.org/question/86126/import-errorno-module-named-rospkg/?comment=87546#comment-87546

I've tried to uninstall my ROS and the reinstall it.
Well after I reinstall I still face the same problem and there is another error coming out somehow ( I guess I have uninstall my ROS in right way ).

**Error:**

(python-yaml had already installed.0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.)

```
user@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

**$PYTHONPATH**

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:
```

Error 2:
No output from echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, it simply blank one row and the back to prompt.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87896/import-error:-no-module-named-rospkg/yaml/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you had an issue with python fixed by a reboot: http://answers.ros.org/question/86126/import-errorno-module-named-rospkg

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-06**:
What am I suppose to do? I can't even get through that 'source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash' right now, I can't move on..

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-06**:
You posted at the link I sent that the problem importing rospkg was fixed when you rebooted.  "Bad marshal data fixed after I reboot my computer." Does that not fix your yaml import issue?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-06**:
No it doesn't. I was thinking that can I append yaml into pythonpath? Something like sys.path ( I don't remember).

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-06**:
No it doesn't. I was thinking that can I append yaml into pythonpath? Something like sys.path ( I don't remember).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-06**:
python-yaml should install into your system path already, next to rospkg suggesting that you have a problem with your python installation in general.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-06**:
I had tried to reinstall python for several times, it doesn't seems to have any different. Any possible mistake somewhere else?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-06**:
It's likely there's a problem with your envionment.  You could try to clear your .bashrc. (keep a backup.) Or another easy way might be to create a new user account and try from it.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-06**:
What do you mean by creating a new user account? I thought that internally the setting will still be the same? If the problem happen in python then it will not make any difference.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-06**:
That's what this test is to verify.  If you can import yaml from another user it is your environment.  If you cannot there's a problem with your greater python installation.